# How can I suppress the browser's authentication dialog?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-authentication

My web application has a login page that submits authentication credentials via an AJAX call. If the user enters the correct username and password, everything is fine, but if not, the following happens:

1. The web server determines that although the request included a well-formed Authorization header, the credentials in the header do not successfully authenticate.
2. The web server returns a 401 status code and includes one or more WWW-Authenticate headers listing the supported authentication types.
3. The browser detects that the response to my call on the XMLHttpRequest object is a 401 and the response includes WWW-Authenticate headers. It then pops up an authentication dialog asking, again, for the username and password.

This is all fine up until step 3. I don't want the dialog to pop up, I want want to handle the 401 response in my AJAX callback function. (For example, by displaying an error message on the login page.) I want the user to re-enter their username and password, of course, but I want them to see my friendly, reassuring login form, not the browser's ugly, default authentication dialog.

Incidentally, I have no control over the server, so having it return a custom status code (i.e., something other than a 401) is not an option.

Is there any way I can suppress the authentication dialog? In particular, can I suppress the Authentication Required dialog in Firefox 2 or later? Is there any way to suppress the Connect to *[host]* dialog in IE 6 and later?

---

**Edit**
*Additional information from the author (Sept. 18):*
I should add that the real problem with the browser's authentication dialog popping up is that it give insufficient information to the user.

The user has just entered a username and password via the form on the login page, he believes he has typed them both correctly, and he has clicked the submit button or hit enter. His expectation is that he will be taken to the next page or perhaps told that he has entered his information incorrectly and should try again. However, he is instead presented with an unexpected dialog box.

The dialog makes no acknowledgment of the fact he just *did* enter a username and password. It does not clearly state that there was a problem and that he should try again. Instead, the dialog box presents the user with cryptic information like "The site says: '*[realm]*'." Where *[realm]* is a short realm name that only a programmer could love.

Web broswer designers take note: no one would ask how to suppress the authentication dialog if the dialog itself were simply more user-friendly. The *entire* reason that I am doing a login form is that our product management team rightly considers the browsers' authentication dialogs to be awful.

Comment: The answer is that there is no good answer. The hacks suggested by Marijn are as close as it gets. Of course, using a custom authentication understood by the server and your JavaScript, but not by the browser, will also do the trick, if that's possible.

Comment: I´ve been at the same issue and found this link in a comment here on stackoverflow (not my blog): http://loudvchar.blogspot.ca/2010/11/avoiding-browser-popup-for-401.html Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this is possible -- if you use the browser's HTTP client implementation, it will always pop up that dialog. Two hacks come to mind:

1. Maybe Flash handles this differently (I haven't tried yet), so having a flash movie make the request might help.
2. You can set up a 'proxie' for the service that you're accessing on your own server, and have it modify the authentication headers a bit, so that the browser doesn't recognise them.

Comment: "Not possible" appears to be the correct answer, although I suspect that the "proxie" hack would do the trick.

Comment: @Stobor The accepted answer for the duplicate that you posted actually links back to this question as its answer!

Comment: @7SpecialGems Good catch. I wasn't suggesting it was a dupe, I linked to the specific answer (the WWW-Authenticate one) which was posted 4 years after the accepted answer. Although in hindsight, I can't remember why I was looking at that, or how I tested it.

Comment: I try to catch unauthorized 401 error by this code:
$.ajaxSetup({
        statusCode: {
            401: function () {
                RedirectToLogin();
            }
        }
    }); But IE always show browser's authentication dialog. How I can suppress this dialog in ASP.Net MVC 2?

Comment: @PaulP, like has been said, you need a proxy that will strip the 401 status code response's of their WWW-Authenticate header, or some sort of custom server implementation.

Comment: the ultimate way is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19102200/1005652 - it *is* possible, I use it for transparent fallback from a failed SPNEGO ( Windows SSO / Kerberos ) authentication.

Comment: If you have control over the web service code you can have it return 403 Forbidden instead.  This is actually more appropriate for an authenticated user that is specifically excluded access to a particular resource.

Comment: For anybody who finds this 10+ years later, I found a [functional workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62895415/26286) that isn't pretty but does work for me in the browsers I've tested so far.  I'd certainly welcome more eyes on the problem, though.

Comment: @dgvid sorry, but "not possible" makes me irrationally angry.  I know what computers can do and it's definitely possible, and it make me furious at whoever designed it to not provide that capability.

Answer (score 57):

I encountered the same issue here, and the backend engineer at my company implemented a behavior that is apparently considered a good practice : when a call to a URL returns a 401, if the client has set the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, the server drops the `www-authenticate` header in its response.

The side effect is that the default authentication popup does not appear.

Make sure that your API call has the `X-Requested-With` header set to `XMLHttpRequest`. If so there is nothing to do except changing the server behavior according to this good practice...

Comment: If the backend is Java/Spring based, the `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` handles this behavior for you.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Many libraries have adopted this behavior including Devise

Comment: any idea how to do this in nginx? "when a call to a URL returns a 401, if the client has set the header X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest, the server drops the www-authenticate header in its response."

Answer (score 22):

The browser pops up a login prompt when both of the following conditions are met:

1. HTTP status is 401
2. `WWW-Authenticate` header is present in the response

If you can control the HTTP response, then you can remove the `WWW-Authenticate` header from the response, and the browser won't popup the login dialog.

If you can't control the response, you can setup a proxy to filter out the `WWW-Authenticate` header from the response.

As far as I know (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong), there is no way to prevent the login prompt once the browser receives the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Comment: Good information.  Regarding valid `WWW-Authenticate` header values, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1748451/225217

Answer (score 9):

I realize that this question and its answers are very old.  But, I ended up here.  Perhaps others will as well.

If you have access to the code for the web service that is returning the 401.  Simply change the service to return a 403 (Forbidden) in this situation instead 401.  The browser will not prompt for credentials in response to a 403.  403 is the correct code for an authenticated user that is not authorized for a specific resource.  Which seems to be the situation of the OP.

From the IETF document on 403:

**A server that receives valid credentials that are not adequate to
   gain access ought to respond with the 403 (Forbidden) status code**

Answer (score 4):

In Mozilla you can achieve it with the following script when you create the XMLHttpRequest object:

```
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.mozBackgroundRequest = true;
xmlHttp.open("GET",URL,true,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

The 2nd line prevents the dialog box....

Comment: This appears to do nothing under Firefox 2. It results in a DOM security error, NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR code 1000, under Firefox 3.

Answer (score 3):

What server technology do you use and is there a particular product you use for authentication?

Since the browser is only doing its job, I believe you have to change things on the server side to not return a 401 status code. This could be done using custom authentication forms that simply return the form again when the authentication fails.

Answer (score 2):

In Mozilla land, setting the mozBackgroundRequest parameter of XMLHttpRequest ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#Attributes)) to true suppresses those dialogs and causes the requests to simply fail.  However, I don't know how good cross-browser support is (including whether the the quality of the error info on those failed requests is very good across browsers.)

Comment: The moz- prefix implies no cross-browser support (unless you can find similar parameters that work in each of the other browsers).

Answer (score 2):

jan.vdbergh has the truth, if you can change the 401 on server side for another status code, the browser won't catch and paint the pop-up.
Another solution could be change the WWW-Authenticate header for another custom header. I dont't believe why the different browser can't support it, in a few versions of Firefox we can do the xhr request with mozBackgroundRequest, but in the other browsers?? here, there is an interesting [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=31582) with this issue in Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue with MVC 5 and VPN where whenever we are outside the DMZ using the VPN, we find ourselves having to answer this browser message. Using .net I simply handle the routing of the error using

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error"  >
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Index"/>
</customErrors>
```

thus far it has worked because the Index action under the home controller validates the user. The view in this action, if logon is unsuccessful, has login controls that I use to log the user in using using LDAP query passed into Directory Services:

```
      DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OurDomain");
      DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
      Dsearch.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + UserID + ")";
      Dsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
```

While this has worked fine thus far, and I must let you know that I am still testing it and the above code has had no reason to run so it's subject to removal... testing currently includes trying to discover a case where the second set of code is of any more use. Again, this is a work in progress, but since it could be of some assistance or jog your brain for some ideas, I decided to add it now... I will update it with the final results once all testing is done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Node, Express & Passport and was struggling with the same issue. I got it to work by explicitly setting the `www-authenticate` header to an empty string. In my case, it looked like this:

```
(err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err) {
    res._headers['www-authenticate'] = ''
    return res.json(err)
  }
}
```

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the similar situation while developing a web app for Samsung Tizen Smart TV. It was required to scan the complete local network but few IP addresses were returning "401 Unauthorized" response with "www-authenticate" header attached. It was popping up a browser authentication pop requiring user to enter "Username" & "Password" because of "Basic" authentication type (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).

To get rid from this, the simple thing which worked for me is setting **credentials: 'omit'** for Fetc Api Call (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Official documentation says that:

To instead ensure browsers don’t include credentials in the request, use credentials: 'omit'

```js
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'omit'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For those unsing C# here's `ActionAttribute` that returns `400` instead of `401`, and 'swallows' Basic auth dialog.

```
public class NoBasicAuthDialogAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(400);
    }
}
```

use like following:

```
[NoBasicAuthDialogAuthorize(Roles = "A-Team")]
public ActionResult CarType()
{
 // your code goes here
}
```

Hope this saves you some time.