# Using javascript with the twitter API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, air

I'm interested in making a twitter client using Adobe Air, but I'm kinda stuck right now, as I can't figure out a better way to connect to the twitter REST API since it needs authentication.

Currently, the client sends a request to my server (a php script using curl) with the twitter username/password (unencrypted) in GET variables. The server then makes a request to twitter using those credentials and outputs the buffer, which gets sent back to the client, which then processes/displays it.

This obviously is a horrendous security hole, so does anyone know of a better (more secure) way of doing it?

**FYI:** I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few Base64 Encoding tools out there.  You can use one of them.  You can add a header with the encoded username and password based on the [Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) specs

Here is a post that does exactly what you want. http://www.aswinanand.com/blog/2009/01/http-basic-authentication-using-ajax/.  The base64 is encoded using this library from [ostermiller.org](http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html)

```
$.ajax({    
  'url': 'http://twitter.com/action/',
  'otherSettings': 'othervalues',
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  " + 
                          encodeBase64(username + ":" + password));
  },
  sucess: function(result) {
   alert('done');
  }
});
```

Comment: true, but last I checked. twitter only supports basic.

Comment: I still get a login prompt when using this technique in FF 3.6.11 - has something changed?

Comment: I've found this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86105/how-can-i-supress-the-browsers-authentication-dialog) that seems to suggest you can't avoid the browsers default login prompt if the details are incorrect.

Comment: Should be `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password)`

Comment: How do you use the encodeBase64 library? There doesn't seem to be a script to download?

Comment: function encodeBase64 not defined in jquery, try use BTOA(username + ":" + password)

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about doing something similar with a PHP proxy server (the app requires more requests than are allowed without whitelisting so I'll need to route requests through a single IP).

My idea is that you only send the username/password combination once and then assign the user a temporary session id that is used for future requests. Sending the initial username/password securely is a little tricky, you could encrypt it with a salt but I don't know how easy AIR apps are to decompile. Another option could be SSL (but I'm still not entirely sure how that works).

Here's a step-by-step guide for the session id concept though:

1. User gives AIR app Twitter credentials.
2. Credentials encrypted and sent to the proxy server.
3. Authentication tested at the proxy.

   - If successful a session is created and the id to use is returned.

     - Note that session contains an expiry date/time and can only be used by one IP.
   - If unsuccessful an error is returned to the client.
4. Client stores session id and uses it in future requests in place of the username/password.

   - E.g. `request.php?action=get&data=friends_timeline&sessid=a3ajh83bah35nf`
   - Session expiry time extended on each update.
5. When user signs out of application a kill message is sent to the proxy and the session is nullified.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at Spaz. http://funkatron.com/spaz - it is an open source Twitter Client written in javascript for Air. The source is available at Google Code. http://code.google.com/p/spaz/

I have not looked that much at the source, but I can see some elements have been written in Flash/Flex. I am using the app however, and it just works.

Hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ada is an Adobe Air Twitter client written in Javascript. You can download it to get an idea of what it does:

http://madan.org/ada

The code for Ada is on GitHub:

http://github.com/sfsam/ada/tree/master

Ada uses Base64. The nice thing about Ada is that the code base is really small so you should be able to figure it all out.