# How do I make AJAX request to actions that require authentication in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rest, devise

I am trying to send an AJAX request to a Rails controller that uses `before_filter` to authenticate the user. The problem is when the request gets sent, the server asks for authentication even if the user is already logged in.

Here is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'DELETE',
  url: "/messages/delete_all",
  data: [1,2,4],
  success: function() {
        console.log("Your request is received.")
    }
});
```

When the user hits `delete_all` from the browser, it works, but with AJAX it doesn't. What gives?

EDIT: could it be related to the `authenticity_token`?

Comment: What kind of authentication do you use? Is it something like http-basic-auth?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I am using Devise, but the pop up that I see is typical to http-basic-auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this question will help: [Using javascript with the twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671042/using-javascript-with-the-twitter-api/671054#671054)

The solution proposed there should look something like this in your case

```
$.ajax({    
  type: 'DELETE',
  url: "/messages/delete_all",
  data: [1,2,4],
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic  " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password)
  },
  success: function() {
    console.log("Your request is received.")
  }
});
```

Comment: Is that secure? Also, where am I going to store and fine the username and password? The users login with facebook.

Comment: It's as secure as Basic Auth. Storing the password and username anywhere in plain text is a bad idea. If the user inputs the information directly it should be just fine IMO.