# Can I coerce Apache into not including a WWW-Authenticate header for failed HTTP Basic Auth?

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, http-authentication

I'm using HTTP Basic Authentication with AJAX requests.  Firefox 3 is a whiner and always displays a dialog box for failed credentials -- even though I don't want one.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86105/how-can-i-supress-the-browsers-authentication-dialog) summarizes some of the browser and JS issues; you'll notice it's unresolved on the client side.  Luckily, I have at least some freedom to change the server -- I can modify my `.htaccess` file.

Basically, whenever Firefox sees the WWW-Authenticate header, it tries to authenticate again.  **Can I suppress that header *only* for AJAX requests by modifying my `.htaccess` file?**  If so, how?  I can pass a custom header in my XHR request if necessary.

Here's what it looks like currently:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/private/.htpasswd
AuthName "Private Collection"
require valid-user
```

Comment: Am I missing how this is different from the question you asked an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928874/how-do-i-keep-firefox-from-prompting-for-username-password-with-http-basic-auth-w

Comment: The previous question was focused on a client-side solution to the problem, which appears to be impossible.  This is focused on a server side solution with a specific server setup and limitations.

Comment: Also, it's a problem that's generalizable out beyond just this one application -- it's about setting headers in general, not about Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem that I solved through a proxy written in nodejs.
Perhaps this can help you: [Write proxy/wrapper class for own service in jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448975/write-proxy-wrapper-class-for-own-service-in-jersey)