# Rest call on expired session: HTTP 401 response causes browser to display login window

Tags: http, rest, session, spring-security, session-timeout

I have written a HTML 5 application that uses AngularJS and interfaces with a Java REST backend running on Tomcat. 
I use Spring Security to handle login and security.

When the user enters the website he is forwarded to a login page which creates a session and redirects to the index page. The REST calls that loads further data from the server then uses that session to authenticate.
If there is no session in place, I fallback to basic authentication over HTTP, such that it is possible to invoke the REST endpoints separately from the web application.

The problem I have now is when the session expires. This causes a `HTTP 401 Unauthenticated` response from the server. I thought I can catch that error and redirect the user back to the login page with Javascript. However before my error handler is called, the browser first shows a login window, only if I click cancel my Javascript error handler can handle the response.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the browser from showing this login window? Or is this a general problem with my application design?

The alternative might be not to use a session at all and to cache username and password in the application. Then I need to send it with every REST call using basic authentication, would that be a better approach?

The following is the HTTP response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Spring Security Application"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 999
Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2013 11:00:34 GMT
```

**Update:** It appears that the reason for this is the `WWW-Authenticate` header, which causes the browser to display the login dialog.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964463/supress-unset-www-authenticate-header-in-apache-401-response

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this. As I mentioned in my update the reason is, that the response contains the `WWW-Authenticate` header field. My solution was then to change the configuration of spring security to return a different header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: FormBased
```

To do this I had to implement the `AuthenticaitonEntryPoint` interface and manually set the header and status code in the response:

```
@Component( "restAuthenticationEntryPoint" )
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                          AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException {
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "FormBased");
        response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED );
    }
}
```

then I changed the configuration of spring-security and set the `entry-point-ref` to point to the new class:

```
<http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <http-basic />
    <session-management />
</http>
```

Comment: With this change, does this affect "such that it is possible to invoke the REST endpoints separately from the web application"? I have the exact same set up as you mentioned, Angular to Spring REST backend, down to having the REST fall back to basic auth to allow it to be invoked separately.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. If you have a problem with the setup, post a separate question and link it here, I will try to answer it.

Comment: We ended up with a similar (but reverse) solution. We added a header to the UI at all times (X-WWW-Authenticate) with a value of false. Then, on the back end we changed the authentication for the REST API to look for this header. If it is there and false, it won't allow or check for basic auth. Otherwise (true or missing) it makes the request. That way, our REST API can remain as is for testing and usability outside the UI.

Comment: Has anyone tested this in all major browsers? Does it work properly in every browser?

Comment: I am not aware of any problems with this approach.

Comment: This might be interesting: http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid changing the server and make it return `WWW-Authenticate` header for all other callers, you can change your client to send its request with `X-Requested-With` header with `XMLHttpRequest` value.
By default, Spring Security will not to send `WWW-Authenticate` for such requests. (see [Spring source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HttpBasicConfigurer.java#L83))