# Server response with different WWW-Authenticate header depending of if request is made by browser or postman

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, restful-authentication, silex

Context:
I have a login form in a SPA that makes an AJAX call to a Silex-PHP API. If the credentials are right, everything works smooth. If the credentials are wrong, the server returns a 401 Unauthorized, and Firefox/Chrome shows the default login form.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86105/how-can-i-supress-the-browsers-authentication-dialog) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928874/how-do-i-keep-firefox-from-prompting-for-username-password-with-http-basic-auth/19102200#19102200) questions to try to avoid the browser from prompting.

One of the suggested solutions is to set the WWW-Authenticate header in the response to something different than Basic. Which I did in my Silex API with:

```
$response->headers->set('WWW-Authenticate', 'FormBased');
```

When making a request via Postman it shows is working:

```
Cache-Control → no-cache
Connection → Keep-Alive
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Fri, 30 Jan 2015 19:13:49 GMT
Keep-Alive → timeout=5, max=100
Server → Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8      
PHP/5.6.2 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
WWW-Authenticate → FormBased <------------------------
X-Powered-By → PHP/5.6.2
```

However, when doing the request via AJAX from the browser, the response looks like:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 30 Jan 2015 19:03:11 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=74
Server  Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8       
PHP/5.6.2 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
WWW-Authenticate    Basic realm="Secured"  <------------------------
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.6.2
```

WWW-Authenticate and Content-Type are different in the responses to the same request.

The AJAX Call is:

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: { 'PHP_AUTH_USER' : formValues.username, 'PHP_AUTH_PW' : formValues.password },
    success:function (data) {
         console.log(["Login request details: ", data]);

         if(data.error) {  // If there is an error, show the error messages
              console.log('error data');
         }
         else { // If not, send them back to the home page
              App.trigger("home:show");
         }
    },
    error:function(){
         console.log('error logging in');
    },
    statusCode: {
         401: function(){
               console.log('401 invalid credentials');
         }
    }
});
```

How can the responses be different? How can I drop or override the WWW-Authenticate header in the response for the browsers?

Comment: Check Content-Type request header.  It's different.

Comment: true, let me look into that,

Comment: these are Response headers, not request. However, you are right, the response should be application/json. I'm more confused now, both are requesting to the same endpoint, and in the backend I am setting: 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'

Comment: Ah yes of course.  An unexpected content-type response could be a sign of a bad content-type request.  So it's probably a bug in your ajaxing code.

Comment: i added my ajax call in case you can see something wrong

Comment: OK it looks fine.  I was thinking maybe your dataType was not set.

Comment: if you have any further ideas on what to try, i'll appreciate em, I am pretty stuck atm :P

Comment: I would use firebug to check ajax request headers are correct.  If request is the same, response should be the same.

Comment: can't see the entirety of the postman request but it seems to match, and the postman request is the one who gets the proper response

Answer (score 0):

This is a related question and how I finally solved the problem:

[How to overwrite a class from the Security Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278410/how-to-overwrite-a-class-from-the-security-component/28282170#28282170)