# Change status code sent back by Restlet for authenication

Tags: java, ajax, restlet, digest-authentication

I am using Restlet with Digest Authentication.  Works well. Except I want to make it a bit more ajax/Javascript friendly by avoiding the browser's authentication dialog pop up when a 401 is first sent back.

This is what I think will work:

1. User/pass obtained using a textfields and stored in javascript object.
2. Ajax call to secure resource.
3. Reselt sends back non-401 code (say 406) with Digest Auth info.
4. Javascript catches code, packages request/user/password into hash, sends to restlet.

a) Will the above work?

b) How do I send a different status code using Digest in Restlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to return non-401 response, since you cannot change the browser behaviour in that the browser will always display the popup.

see also [How to prevent browser to invoke basic auth popup and handle 401 error using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859627/how-to-prevent-browser-to-invoke-basic-auth-popup-and-handle-401-error-using-jqu)

you change the response by modifying/overriding the DigestAuthenticator and setting a different response, or use a filter that will detect a 401 and switch it to another status.

Comment: I think the filter is a good way to go. I am new to restlet, any code hints on how it would work in a filter?

Comment: not much different from a simple servlet filter, just implement afterhandle and change the status code;