# Web API - How do I remove WWW-Authenticate header in response message with unauthorized request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created authorize attribute in some controller. When my browser using jquery call this api to get data, it gets unauthorized 401 status code, my browser always show authencation popup. It is ugly. I think it can be resolved by remove WWW-Authenticate header? How do I remove it in Web API.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent browser to invoke basic auth popup and handle 401 error using Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859627/how-to-prevent-browser-to-invoke-basic-auth-popup-and-handle-401-error-using-jqu)

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTTP specification, when responding with status code 401, the server MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.htmt

Comment: But what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I use jquery to make a ajax request to server but how to prevent authentication popup when i get 401 response status code? Thank you

Comment: @PhuongTT doing this in web.config will fix the issue `<authorization>
      <!--<deny users="?" />-->
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>`