# Authentication required? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, passwords, alert

i was just wondering how you can require an authentication for your website. such like this in the picture:
https://kb.tanium.com/images/thumb/5/58/AuthenticationRequired.png/700px-AuthenticationRequired.png

Can you do this with javascipt?
Thanks for help

Comment: No. This needs to be done server-side.

Comment: Google "Basic Authentication"

Comment: you can write the code in <javascript> tag in HTML or write that in a separate .js file and include that file in your jsp or HTML page

Comment: The example in the image probably uses htaccess. JavaScript runs in the browser, so you can't rely only on it for any security features as it can easily be subverted.

Comment: @akshayjain what you are saying is where to do javascript code the OP is not asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

That's a basic [HTTP response code 401](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) that is sent to the browser upon a request.
You can do it on your webserver by securing a folder/page with [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/htaccess.html) or directive, or you can return a 401 http response in your code (java, php or whatever you use) for example in java:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

Normally handle of 401 responses is the job of the browser, this has nothing to do with javascript. However you can try to change the defaut behavior of the browser by using javascript, try to take a look at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859627/how-to-prevent-browser-to-invoke-basic-auth-popup-and-handle-401-error-using-jqu). I'd recommend not doing so but instead do a html form that you can freely customize and let it return a form with your identifiers.