# Remove pop-up an alert-box "Authorization required" using JS

Tags: javascript, api, rest

I work with the API, located in my same site. Backend requires each request header encrypted login / password system Basic HTTP Authentication - [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

If the data entry entered incorrectly - takes off here is a warning:
[image: Authentication required, to access the server http://gkeep.ua:80 you've to provide your credentials. Server message: Secured Area]

**Rough translation**

> Authentication required, to access the server http://gkeep.ua:80 you've to provide your credentials. Server message: Secured Area

it is the same type as a normal `alert ()`, `prompt ()` and `confirm ()`
I would like to disable this window by overriding function

```
window.alert = function () {}; alert (12345); // does not work
```

but it appeared that it is not `alert ()`, `audio prompt ()` or `confirm ()`
it is generally different, and how to turn it off, I do not understand

can someone faced with such a task, I will be grateful if you tell me how to solve it

Answer (score 4):

> it is the same type as a normal alert (), prompt () and confirm ()

No, it is not. It’s the authentication dialog brought up by the browser when it receives an HTTP status code `401 Unauthorized`, JavaScript has nothing to do with – and that’s why you can not “disable” it via JavaScript either.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry cant comment because of reputation

Look this question
[How to prevent browser to invoke basic auth popup and handle 401 error using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859627)

and this
[JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501)

Comment: The first link provides some good discussion on that. The second one about alert is not relevant though.