# ExtJS: Suppress browser popup on 401

Tags: extjs, browser, popup, http-status-code-401

I am writing a small client application with ExtJS that reaches out a web service out there in universe. My problem is, when user enters wrong credentials, server throws a 401 exception. I am handles it

```
callback: function (records, operation, success){
    if (operation.error.status == 401){
        filedset.setInstructions("Invalid credentials");
    } else{
       //handle other exceptions
    }
}
```

But my custom message is overridden by browser popup asking for credentials. How can I suppress that popup. I have no control over server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859627/how-to-prevent-browser-to-invoke-basic-auth-popup-and-handle-401-error-using-jqu

Comment: Suggestions mentioned there includes throwing a different exception or modifying header content from server. I already mentioned in my question, I have no control over sever side

Comment: I know, and that post explains that there are no other options unfortunately.

Comment: @ Ivan Samovar answer mentioned with security issues,  @ sedu answer didn't worked. Could you please let me know the specific answer you are referring. Thanks!