# Suppress WWW-Authenticate header in Azure IIS

Tags: angularjs, azure, authentication, iis, basic-authentication

I am dealing with a third party REST API server which uses `Basic Authentication`. We don't have control over that server and in case of a `401` chrome pops up a dialog for username and password which is essentially because of the `WWW-Authenticate` header which is present in the response in case of a `401`. We have a reverse proxy setup on Azure through which all the requests are being made to the API server. I am wondering if there is a way we can suppress/remove the `WWW-Authenticate` header in the reverse proxy IIS webconfig somehow. Or is there any other way to suppress this dialog without the help from the API server itself. The front-end is an Angular application. Thanks in Advance!

Update: We are able to achieve the same in our local dev environment where we are using `nginx` by just adding `proxy_hide_header WWW-Authenticate;` to the server.conf file. Does `IIS` has something similar that can be used to strip that header from the response?

Comment: Is your angular js application sending HTTP request against to your 3rd party rest api, and which responding 401?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT yes that is what is happening

Comment: Check the answer for suppressing WWW-Authenticate header in IIS at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859627/how-to-prevent-browser-to-invoke-basic-auth-popup-and-handle-401-error-using-jqu)