# How to close sign in popup window opened automatically by the browser for a failed basic authentication scheme?

Tags: angular, browser, basic-authentication, www-authenticate

I am making a HTTP post request from my angular 6 application to a server to get the authentication token. The server is using basic authentication scheme to validate the username and password before issuing the token. The server responds with `401 unauthorized error` if the login `username` and `password` are incorrect. Along with `401 error`, the server returns `www-authenticate: Basic realm={some message}` header. The browser automatically pops up a sign in dialog to enter `username` and `password` on failed login. I don't want to make any changes in the server, instead I want to handle this popup in my angular application.

I want this popup to be disabled on failed logins and instead I want to handle the error in my angular application itself.

Is that possible?

If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86105/how-can-i-suppress-the-browsers-authentication-dialog)

In other words, you can't do that but you can still find some tricks on the topic above.