# React Axios Basic Authentication, how to prevent pop up dialog box from showing

Tags: reactjs, axios, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I have implemented an API with Basic Authentication

When I provide the correct username and password to the authentication, it works fine,

However, the problem is when i provide the wrong username / password to the request, how to prevent the Sign In dialog from pop-up

Here is my axios request code,

```
axios.post(url, {}, {
  auth: {
    'username': 'wrong username',
    'password': 'wrong password'
  }
})
```

How to prevent this dialog box from showing when I provide the wrong username / password

[image]

Comment: Found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86105/how-can-i-suppress-the-browsers-authentication-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but you can try setting this property `validateStatus`. It will make axios ignore error status code and just return result in response callback.

```
axios.post(url, {}, {
  auth: {
    'username': 'wrong username',
    'password': 'wrong password'
  },
  validateStatus: function (status) {
    return true;
  },
})
```

Comment: The dialog pop up still exist. Does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to answer, but i found a solution for this I didn't saw anywhere. It's something really dumb but I just didn't know it existed before.

Try adding these lines on your main.js file :

```
  axios.defaults.auth = {
  username : "xxx", 
  password : "zzz"
  }
```

With of course, the good informations.

Just to be clear, I'm using Axios, Vue JS and FastAPI.

I don't know if it'll help you, but hopefully it'll help someone else.